# JW Player Streaming Config Best Practices

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am setting up an embedded JW Player on my site to play live stream videos in a number of file formats. I am looking to confirm I am using best practices in the stream setup.

**Background:**
The live streams are hosted on other networks and all of the stream variables are stored in a local DB. Calling the DB for a stream currently returns 4 variables; **file**, **image**, **title** and **primary**. I am using JW Player Premium and `<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/xxxxxx.js"></script>` has been loaded to my `<head>`

**My Question:**
Are there any additional fields or properties I need to call/set to fully define all supported stream types? Are there any additional fields I should have in my DB? It almost seems to simple!?

Here is my current code:

```
script.
    function loadVideo(myFile,myImage,myTitle,myPrimary) {
      jwplayer().load([{
        file: myFile,
        image: myImage,
        title: myTitle,
        primary: myPrimary
      }])
      jwplayer().play()
    }
```

Player dimension characteristics (width, height, etc) are defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Are you planning to use RTMP streaming, which is Flash and therefore is not supported on mobiles, or HLS streaming, which requires at least a JW Player Premium license? In either case, do you want to provide some sort of fallback for users who don't have Flash installed (HLS on most desktops still requires Flash).

Comment: I have streams both RTMP and HLS streams. Is the fallback support accomplished by defining a the primary and fallback files in a playlist?

Comment: Yes, using the "sources" attribute. See http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1710454-configuring-multiple-sources

Comment: Indeed, just use RTMP, with a fallback to HLS. Or if you have Premium, just use HLS with a fallback to MP4.